# How to fetch history of user specific push notifications from parse in iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, notifications

I have implemented an iOS app with parse integration for data handling. App uses push notifications services provided by Parse. I am using Parse PUSH console to send the push notification based upon user email ID and its working. Till now everything is fine. The problem is with fetching the notifications data of that user from Parse. I couldn't find any way to fetch the notifications history of the user.

I have only one option i.e create new table in Parse and store the notifications information in that table whenever app receives a push notification so that I can query from that table.

But the problem is if the app is not running in the background and user has not lunched the app then notifications data could not be stored in the newly created table as the app is not awake.

Is there any update from the Parse team or any other solution to get this work done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

all the notifications that are sent by parse-server are stored in **_PushStatus** collection. This is also the collection that parse dashboard fetch the data from. 
What you can do is to see what kind of data there is in this collection and create a query that will fetch the data that you need from it.
You can use mongo CLI in order to display this collection or Mongo admin UI tool like MongoDB compass.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ran Hassid.  to see the data in that collection, I have created one query like below.                                                     PFQuery *brandsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_PushStatus"];
    NSError *error;
    PFObject *userParseObject = [brandsQuery getFirstObject:&error];  this throws error as class name contains special character. Is it possible to get the history using that collection from the app side?

Comment: Good question ... never tried it . i will check it and will let you know.

Comment: From what i see... the PushStatus collection is not expose via rest API. what you can do is create a middleware (via app.use("/{SOME_PATH"....}) and this middleware will access mongodb and return the data to the client. From the client you will need to execute a REST call. this is something that can be achieved also using cloud code.

Comment: Thank you Ran. I will try to implement it as you explained.